# How do I remove substrings in quotations from a string? (Without Regex)

Tags: java, string

I have a text file that contains the following: 
Bob went to "the store" the store to "buy milk" buy milk.

I want to remove all quoted material from string1 so it simply contains: Bob went to the store to buy milk.

Is there a way to do this without using Regex? I'm currently trying to use the split() method. I begin by reading the text file into a String variable named string1, using split(), then storing values back into a new string named newString.

```
String string1 = new Scanner(new File("C:/bob.txt")).useDelimeter("\\A").next();       
String newString = "";

String[] arr = string1.split("\"");
for (int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
    newString += arr[y];
}
```

I'm very new to java and not sure if I am using the split method correctly. When I print out newString, it reads as "Bob went to the store the store to buy milk"

My problem is that it should say "Bob went to the store to buy milk." The string is missing the period on the end, and it writes "the store" twice.

Can anyone help me make this work? (If there is a better way than split() I would like to know. I would also like it to work for a string with any number of quoted sections. Also no pattern matching/Regex) Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to use regex?

Comment: I would have recommended using the `String#replaceAll` method, but it uses a regex.

Comment: "I'm currently trying to use the split() method" split is using regex...

Comment: arshajii, this is practice for a midterm. We are expected to be able to do this operation with and without Regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Bob went to \"the store\" the store to \"buy milk\" buy milk.";
    boolean inQuotes = false;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == '"') inQuotes = !inQuotes;
        else if (!inQuotes) sb.append(str.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Note that the result `"Bob went to  the store to  buy milk."` has double spaces between `to  the store` and `to  buy milk`, because it just deletes what is in between the quotes.

Comment: This is good, but can I convert the variable sb from StringBuilder to String? the reason I ask is because things like StringTokenizer won't work on sb

Comment: Convert to String by calling StringBuilder.toString()

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8's `stream` to stream through `character array` of `string` and skip double quotes via `filter`, e.g.:

```
String s = "Bob blah blah \"quote\" blah \"another quote\"";
System.out.println(s);
String string = s.chars()
.filter(c -> c != '"')
.collect(StringBuilder::new, 
        StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
.toString();
System.out.println(string);
```

Another approach would be to simply loop through `char` array and skip double quotes, e.g.:

```
String s = "Bob blah blah \"quote\" blah \"another quote\"";
System.out.println(s);
StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();
for(char c : s.toCharArray()){
    if(c != '"'){
        s1.append(c);
    }
}
System.out.println(s1.toString());
```